# Angular AOT Build: Internal error: unknown identifier undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

My current Angular 2 project started before Angular supported the AOT feature. Now, I’m trying to get it to work. I'm receiving the following error and I've no clue what this means and where I can start to debug the issue:

```
ERROR in Error: Internal error: unknown identifier undefined
at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24211:23)
at tokenExpr (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18577:39)
at providerDef (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18480:20)
at ...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18697:77
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at NgModuleCompiler.compile (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18697:44)
at AotCompiler._compileModule (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24144:32)
at ...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24056:66
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at AotCompiler._compileImplFile (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24056:19)
at ...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23969:87
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at AotCompiler.emitAllImpls (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23969:52)
at CodeGenerator.emit (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:42:46)
at ...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:33:61
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Dependencies

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/common": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/router": "^4.4.4",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"primeng": "^4.2.1",
"quill": "^1.3.2",
"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
"zone.js": "^0.8.18"
```

Has anyone an idea why this error occurs?

Comment: On a project with many modules it helps to add console.out statements to "tokenExpr" method in "compiler.umd.js" to identify offending module, just print out the "ctx" parameter which should give you the path to broken module

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I faced the same error in my Angular 6 project.

when you run "ng build --prod", read the warning messages carefully. In which file it throws warning message (for eg:dataservice.ts).

then go to that (dataService.ts) file and remove the @Injectable.

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Then try to build again. It works for me.

Answer (score 13):

This part of the application caused the problem:

```
export function windowFactory(): any {
    return window;
}

providers: [{
    provide: Window,
    useFactory: windowFactory
}],
```

[Github: This fails with AoT compiler in Angular CLI, because Window (the browser window) is an interface](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12631#issuecomment-274260009)

Comment: Hi, what you did to fix the factory in the provider ?

Comment: @Injectable()
export class WindowWrapper extends Window {

}

export function getWindow() {
 return window;
}

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error when trying to provide Date for injection instead of an injection token.

So I did:

```
providers: [
    { provide: Date, useValue: new Date() }
  ]
```

and changed it to

```
providers: [
    { provide: NOW, useValue: new Date() },
  ],
```

where `NOW` is defined in the service that depends on it like this

```
export const NOW = new InjectionToken<Date>('now');
```

All documented on the [Angular site](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectiontoken).

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness since I stumbled upon the same error in a different context. The error occurred in my build when using an upgraded angularjs service class that was exported as `default`

```
// Service definition
export default class MyService { /* Registered AngularJS service here */ }

// Module
import MyService from './my-service'

// Upgrade 
export function myServiceFactory(i:any) {
  return i.get('myService');
}

// ngUpgraded Angular main module 
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: MyService, useFactory: myServiceFactory, deps: ['$injector'] }
  ]
})
```

Removing the default export resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I created a base class for my services that uses HttpClient.

The base class and the sub class were marked as `Injectable`.

I removed `Injectable` from the base class and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running on Angular 11 (upgraded over time from 7).  I just received this error but it was because I accidentally reverted my `tsconfig.json` file.  The `enableIvy` line in `angularCompilerOptions` was reverted to the following setup that **caused** the error (for me at least):

```json
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

With Angular 11, the `enableIvy` line should be removed.  My **working** `angularCompilerOptions` became:

```json
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
```

I'm pretty sure the upgrade to 11 set this correctly but I messed up a revert.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to my due to **Class Inheritance**, where both the BaseClass and the DriveClass had `@Injectable` decorator.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BaseService { 
  ... 
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DriveService extends BaseService {
 ... 
}
```

Removing the `@Injectable` from the BaseService solved the problem.

Comment: This was the issue in my case. Thanks for this. I would've spent hours debugging

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem twice and search for it twice.
I just put my answer here for myself in future :)

In my case, this problem occurs when I create 2 projects:

- **my-lib** (which contains common components that can be built as a library and publish to npmjs)
- **my-app** (main application)

This is what I did:

1. In **my-lib**, there is one class:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyFirstService implement IMyFirstService {
}
```

2. In **my-app**, I declare one module which consume the service above:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: MY_FIRST_SERVICE_INJECTION_TOKEN,
            useClass: MyFirstService
        }
    ]
})
export class MyLittleModule {
}
```

3. When I ran `ng build --prod`, the exception occurs.

This is how I fix:

- Remove the `Injectable()` annotation from `MyFirstService` class. The exception has gone.

Finally, I just want to say to my future me:

- Hey myself, if you read this, that means this is nth times you forgot about this painful issue. :v

Answer (score 0):

Check your templates maybe you used a variable in the template which is not defined in the component

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on im4ever's answer, I ran into this same issue. It only showed up when doing a build when setting the configuration, not on `ng serve` or just `ng build` which led me to believe that it is an AOT issue.

When registering a service using a factory method, which I was doing so that I could inject localStorage, I had my module setup like this (shortened for brevity).

```
providers: [
    {provide: StateService, useFactory: provideStateService}
  ],
```

What I did to fix the issue was remove the `@Injectable({})` decorator that I **also** had on the `StateService` class definition.  Once I removed that, errors all went away.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem while running ng build --prod for Angular 7.1.4, so I removed the @Injectable that Karthi Coimbatore recommended for a TooltipService I created to use Angular Material tooltip's positions.